# With Infragistics,how can i mark a Specific point in SplineChart?

Tags: c#, infragistics

Now i have a DataGridView control bingding with some data from DB , and a SplineChart shows the data . i would like to hightlight or mark the Specific point in the Chart when i click the data in the DataGridView control.

what i use to draw the chart is Infragistics ultraChart(SplineChart),C# WinForm.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the charts ChartDrawItem method to customize the color of specific data points.  There is an example of this in Sung's [Chart University](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/sung_kim/archive/2008/09/05/chart-university-chart-101-and-some-201-301-401-stuff.aspx) blog post in the Changing the Color of an Item Based on a Condition (2D only) section.